# Invalid object name 'CarYear'

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to make this statement where if the cars year is newer than 2012, it will print it. Then if it is older than 2012, it will print that. The only problem is that it is giving me the invalid object name.Attached is my car table and my code I tried doing.

```
CREATE TABLE CAR
(
    CarID       CHAR(8)     PRIMARY KEY, -- Primary key
    StoreID     CHAR(4),
    CarMake     VARCHAR(30),
    CarModel    VARCHAR(30),
    CarYear     CHAR(4),
    NeworUsed   VARCHAR(6),
    CarPrice    DECIMAL (6,2),
);


ALTER PROC CarYear
    @CarYear CHAR(4)
AS
BEGIN
    IF( 
        SELECT CarYear
        FROM CAR
        WHERE CarYear = @CarYear   
    ) >= 2012
    BEGIN 
        PRINT 'This car is newer than 2012!'
    END
    ELSE 
        PRINT 'Car is older than 2012'
END
```

Comment: If you double click error message in management studio it even show you bad line

Comment: Why is CarYear a char and not an int??

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE CAR
(
CarID CHAR (8) PRIMARY KEY, -- Primary key
StoreID CHAR(4),
CarMake VARCHAR(30),
CarModel VARCHAR(30),
CarYear CHAR(4), -- better if you change to int type
NeworUsed VARCHAR(6),
CarPrice DECIMAL (6,2),
);

go
--change alter to create 
create proc CarYear

@CarYear char (4)

AS

BEGIN
-- add TOP 1, otherwise if you will have more than 1 record you'll get error
if( select TOP 1 CONVERT(INT,CarYear)

from CAR

where CONVERT(int,CarYear)= CONVERT(int,@CarYear)
-- CarYear is char type and you compare to int type
) >= 2012

begin 

print 'This car is newer than 2012!'
end

else 

print 'Car is older than 2012'

ENDCO
```

Comment: you do not need to use ORDER BY you use only one value

Comment: Yeah, you do, if you want to have a deterministic value. Otherwise WHICH of the multiple rows returned is undefined and potentially random. It's just good practice to ALWAYS specify an ORDER BY when using TOP.

Comment: In this case you have condition so you get nothing or CarYear=@CarYear , so TOP 1 works the same like DISTINCT in this case, so do I still order by?